# Matrix display without row and column names?

Tags: r, matrix

I have this code in R:

```
seq1 <- seq(1:20)
mat <- matrix(seq1, 2)
```

and the result is:

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
> [1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17    19
> [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
> ```

Does R have an option to suppress the display of column names and row names so that I don't get the [,1] [,2] and so on?

Comment: do you mean in the `R` console? or when you export from `R`?

Comment: Also note that in R you don't need the semicolons at the end of the statement.  And `mat` isn't a command.  I'm assuming you mean `matrix(seq1, 2)` because your command doesn't work...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to retain the dimension names but just not print them, you can define a new print function.

```
print.matrix <- function(m){
write.table(format(m, justify="right"),
            row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F)
}

> print(mat)
 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: I would use the ellipsis term in the parent function, and pass it through to the format function, so the options available to format can be accessed by print.matrix, ie, scientific=FALSE etc...

Comment: AFAICT, `print.matrix` is no longer supported and has been replaced by `prmatrix`, which used to be an alias.

Answer (score 4):

This works for matrices:

```
seq1 <- seq(1:20)
mat <- matrix(seq1, 2)

dimnames(mat) <-list(rep("", dim(mat)[1]), rep("", dim(mat)[2]))
mat
```

Answer (score 3):

There is, also, `?prmatrix`:

```
prmatrix(mat, collab = rep_len("", ncol(mat)), rowlab = rep_len("", ncol(mat)))
#                          
# 1 3 5 7  9 11 13 15 17 19
# 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution by [Fojtasek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368356/1834057) is probably the best, but here is another using sprintf instead.

```
print.matrix <- function(x,digits=getOption('digits')){
  fmt <- sprintf("%% .%if",digits)
  for(r in 1:nrow(x))
    writeLines(paste(sapply(x[r,],function(x){sprintf(fmt,x)}),collapse=" "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> writeLines(apply(format(matrix(1:20,2)),1,paste,collapse=" "))
 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
> writeLines(apply(matrix(1:20,2),1,paste,collapse=" "))
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```