# Create proper table in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of number in R that I want to add row names to:

```
t<-c(1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7)
table(t)
1 3 4 5 6 7 
3 3 2 2 2 4 

t <- t(as.data.frame(table(t),optional = FALSE))
row.names(t) <- c("first_row", "second_row")
```

How do I add row names to make it look like:

```
 Row1 Title   1 3 4 5 6 7 
 Row2 Title   3 3 2 2 2 4 


           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
first_row  "1"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7" 
second_row "3"  "3"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "4"
```

This is what i get but how do I take off the "" and column headers?

Comment: row.names(x) <- value

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366596/matrix-display-without-row-and-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

You might be satisfied with something like this

```
t <- t(as.data.frame(table(t)))
row.names(t) <- c("first_row", "second_row")
```

Explanation:
- Convert the table into a data.frame so that you will have the tabular data as a 6x2 data.frame (note that if you convert it to a matrix, you'll lose a dimension. There might be a way to overwrite this behaviour but I haven't looked into that)
- Transpose the data.frame since by default it will convert the table into a long format and it looks like you want a wide format. The transpose operation also converts it into a matrix, which is fine now because it will retain the correct dimensions.
- Now we just need to add the row names

If any of these steps confuse you, experiment with them separately, and try converting to matrix/data.frame before/after transposition to see the different results.

Hope this helps

Comment: That works but all the data has "" around it with headers for the columsn. Do you know how I can remove the "" and headers? See update.

Comment: `write.table(t, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)` Though I strongly recommend not to call objects in the global environment with function names

Comment: Now you just want to convert character data into numeric.  The quotes are around the numbers because the underlying data type is character.  There are many ways to achieve this, I can't comment on which one is the best/most correct one. For example, you can change the class of the matrix to numeric with `class(t) <- "numeric"`. Or you can convert the data.frame into a numeric matrix with `data.matrix` like this `t <- t(data.matrix(as.data.frame(table(t))))`. There are other, probably better, ways.  I agree with David that it's not a good idea to have a variable named `t`