# How to understand a specific function in R

Tags: r

Here I have a simple function in R below it is:

```
no.dimnames <- function(a) {
## Remove all dimension names from an array for compact printing.
d <- list()
l <- 0
for(i in dim(a)) {
d[[l <- l + 1]] <- rep("", i)
}
dimnames(a) <- d
a
}
```

The goal for this function is to drop all array names. However, I dont know what does the following indexing do.

```
d[[l <- l + 1]]
```

In this case, d is a null list initially, and l<- 0 so then d[[0<- 1]] implies what?

```
> x <- matrix(sample(1:5,20,replace=TRUE),nrow = 5)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    4    5    3
[2,]    2    1    5    1
[3,]    1    3    4    4
[4,]    3    1    4    3
[5,]    5    3    5    5
> no.dimnames(x)

 5 4 5 3
 2 1 5 1
 1 3 4 4
 3 1 4 3
 5 3 5 5
```

Comment: `d[[0<- 1]]` isn't valid... you are saying set `0` to `1` which can't be done. In this case `l` is being set to `l + 1` where it is initially 0 so it is `l <- 0 + 1`.

Comment: also.. I wouldn't call d a null list. That is not true. It is an empty list. Not the same thing.

Comment: If the goal is simply to drop dimnames, then just drop 'em: `\`dimnames<-\`(d, NULL)`. The function is already there...

Comment: @Frank Yes you are right, but this is the details about that function and I want to know how the mechanism works

Comment: Assuming you just care how the matrix looks, not its actual dimnames: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9366596/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you understand the increment code `d[[l <- l + 1]]` but are still asking about the empty spaces `rep("", i)`. They are replacing the dimension names with blanks. The `i` is used to indicate the amount of spaces that are needed.

If we had a 4x5 matrix. We would have four row names and five column names. To make them all blank, we would need four spaces in rows `rep("", 4)` and five in columns `rep("", 5)`. The code aims to accomplish that:

```
mat <- matrix(1:20, 4,5)
rownames(mat) <- month.abb[1:4]
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:5]

mat
#     a b  c  d  e
# Jan 1 5  9 13 17
# Feb 2 6 10 14 18
# Mar 3 7 11 15 19
# Apr 4 8 12 16 20


dimnames(mat)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

#What we need
list(rep("", 4), rep("", 5))
# [[1]]
# [1] "" "" "" ""
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "" "" "" "" ""

dimnames(mat) <- list(rep("", 4), rep("", 5))

mat
# 
# 1 5  9 13 17
# 2 6 10 14 18
# 3 7 11 15 19
# 4 8 12 16 20
```

Comment: This answer doesn't come close to answering the question..... You're just showing how to get rid of the names which the OPs function does...

Comment: Your answer addresses the assignment mine addresses the position structure. OP is showing confusion on both ends. Together hopefully they will understand the dimension function they were given.

Answer (score 0):

`d[[0<- 1]]` isn't valid... you are saying set `0` to `1` which can't be done. In this case `l` is being set to `l + 1` where it is initially `0` so it is `l <- 0 + 1`

Forget about what `a` is or what it could be.

Just type this into Rstudio or w/e you are using you will see what happens if you check each variable.

```
> d <- list()
> l <- 0
> d[[l <- l + 1]] <- rep("", 1)
> d
> l
```

The one part I should explain is in this case when you type the `d[[l <- l + 1]]` it is assigning `l + 1` to `l` and then using `l` as the parameter for the `[[]]`.

So the `d[[l <- l + 1]]` breaks down to this...

```
l <- l + 1
l <- 0 + 1
l <- 1
[l]
[[l]]
d[[l]]
d[[1]]
```

Comment: I'm sure that isn't the perfect breakdown, but you should get a pretty good idea what is going on there.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But what is d[[1]] in this case? If I have a 3*2 matrix, then dim(a) will return 3 and 2, that means d[[1]]= "" "" "", then d[[1]]= "" "" ? How does it relate to row names and column names?

Comment: If you don't mind go ahead and post a sample of what you are using. I want to verify what I have.

Comment: @BrattSwan .... your no.dimnames function works on the example you provide

Comment: @BrattSwan so what I don't think I understand is you're saying what does it imply? But I've explained what it does. At no point in time does `0 <- 1` ever occur. It is `l <- 1` where `l` is a variable to be set to 1.