# Print matrix without column names but kept alligned?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to print a matrix without column names and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368356/6377734). However, this will result in the columns of the output not being aligned anymore, when the row names are kept and are of different length:

```
m <- matrix(LETTERS[1:12],nrow = 2, ncol = 6)
rownames(m) <- c("First Row", "Second Row")
```

Using `print` just ignores the `col.names = FALSE` argument (why?):

```
print(m, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
>            [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
> First Row  A    C    E    G    I    K   
> Second Row B    D    F    H    J    L
```

Using `write.table` as proposed removes the alignment:

```
write.table(format(m, justify="right"), col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
> First Row A C E G I K
> Second Row B D F H J L
```

What can I do to keep row names and the alignment intact?

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want matrix or table class, then you can use data frame, by using that you can easily hide column names and make data kept aligned.

```
>d = as.data.frame(m)
>colnames(d)=NULL
>d                   
 First Row  A C E G I K
 Second Row B D F H J L
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Printing data frame while controlling row names and column names
  
# Create example data frame, df

m <- matrix(LETTERS[1:12],nrow = 2, ncol = 6)
rownames(m) <- c("First Row", "Second Row")
colnames(m) <- c("V1","v2","v3","V4","V5","V6")
df <- as.data.frame(m)

# Print data frame with both row names and column names

print(df)

# Print data frame without row names but with column names

print(row.names=FALSE,df)

# Print data frame with row names but without column names

unname(df)

# Print data frame without row names and without column names

print(row.names=FALSE,unname(df))
```