# Printing a data.frame without column names

Tags: r

I have a simple data.frame

```
(distr.freq = data.frame(n.dip=0:3, n.imprese=4:7))
```

I would like to transpose it and print it without showing the column names of the transpose data.frame.
This does not work

```
library(dplyr)

distr.freq %>% t  %>% as.data.frame %>%
  print(colnames = FALSE)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: data.frames always have column names.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
`rownames<-`(as.matrix(t(distr.freq)), NULL)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    1    2    3
#> [2,]    4    5    6    7
```

Or if you don't want the indices to display you could do:

```r
invisible(sapply(distr.freq, cat, "\n"))
#> 0 1 2 3 
#> 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting. But I realize that a (quite simple) solution is given here (sorry! for posting something that was already been solved!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760888/print-matrix-without-column-names-but-kept-alligned